# SSIS Merge Join: Delete does not work

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ssis, merge, data-flow

I've set up a Data Flow Task to sync a flat file with its destination table using a Merge Join with a Left Outer Join as described [here](http://www.rad.pasfu.com/index.php?/archives/150-Insert,-Update,-and-Delete-Destination-table-with-SSIS.html) (and [elsewhere](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5082/synchronize-table-data-using-a-merge-join-in-ssis/)).

[image]

**Merge Join**:
[image]

Inserting and Updating works fine, however, deleting a record from the flat file does nothing.

I guess it's something with the **Conditional Split**: delete `ISNULL(gid_csv) && !ISNULL(gid)`

[image]

or the following SQL Command: `DELETE FROM dbo.gusers WHERE gid = ?`

[image]

The OLE DB Source and the three destinations are accessing the same table.

What do I miss?

Comment: Should I delete my question? It might be helpful to others, however, the tutorials are actually clear about this.

Comment: I would leave it. Self answers are useful as well. There is nothing as frustrating as having a problem, finding the same problem on some discussion site, and the answer being "Never mind - I figured it out myself"

Answer (score 1):

The answer is actually pretty easy:

You have to use a **Full Outer Join** instead of a Left Outer Join in the Merge Join Task.

The referenced tutorials actually told me to do so, I guess I mixed it up with another tutorial that did not include the merge delete.